# simple getopts c problems

Tags: c, getopt, getopts

So I have a pretty simple program but for some reason I can't get the options right.

- If the -h option is present I just want to print the usage statement and exit.
- If no options are present I want it to just run normally.
- If any other options are present I want it to print the usage and EXIT_FAILURE

For some reason I just can't get these results.  I know its a simple fix I just can't seem to find the answer.

Right now this is what I have.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   int c;

   while(( c = getopt( argc, argv, "h")) != -1){
      switch( c ){
      case 'h':
         usage(); return EXIT_SUCCESS;

      case '*':
         usage(); return EXIT_FAILURE;

      default:
         break;
      }
   }
   mainProgram();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Move your `case '*':` into `default:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the `getopt(3)` man page:

> If  getopt()  does  not  recognize  an option character, it prints an error message to stderr,
>   stores the character in optopt, and returns '?'.  The calling program may  prevent  the  error
>   message by setting opterr to 0.

So, `getopt()` will return `?` if someone passes in an unrecognized option.  You're looking for `*`, which you will never receive.  In C, `*` does not act as a wildcard so this does not mean "any character".

Using `default` here isn't the correct solution (although it will work), because this would also trigger on valid options for which you had not implemented a handler.

Comment: Great that worked.  Feel really dumb hahahaha.  Just got so used to shell scripting I guess.  Thanks for the answer.